# How do I update my Minecraft world without it recreating unexplored chunks to the new version?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I run a Minecraft server with an Earth map on 1.12.2. However, I downloaded the map and did not create it myself. I believe most of it was created with world painter, and because of this, many chunks have not been actually loaded by players.

I have tested updating the version it runs on in a singleplayer game, only to realize that the chunks that players had not loaded were regenerated according to the map's seed on that version. For example, if I loaded in, flew around a little and generated some chunks, and then I updated it to 1.13 from 1.12, it would regenerate everything I did not load in, erasing the rest of the Earth map.

Keep in mind, this quite a large map (around 40k blocks long and 16k blocks wide), so it would bring great pains to fly around and preload the entirety of the map before updating the version. Is there any way to keep the map the way it is and update it? Perhaps there is a way to protect the chunks I don't want to be regenerated?

Comment: Do you know if there's a 1.13 version of the map?

Comment: there might be. i'll look back at where i found it originally, but it would suck to lose everything the players already made

Comment: @Ola Please only add the [tag:minecraft-server] tag to questions that are actually specific to servers. The tag doesn't belong here because an identical problem could occur on a singleplayer world.

Comment: That's odd. The game shouldn't differ between manually loaded chunks and such that are created with external tools. A valid chunk is a valid chunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with versions, unexplored chunks are always generated when you first load them. You have a few options against this:

- If everyone is always in Spectator mode, running `/gamerule spectatorsGenerateChunks false` will prevent generating new chunks entirely.
- If everyone is always in one of the other three gamemodes, you can keep them inside the generated area using the world border.
- You could change the world type to "superflat" with the preset "void" (added in 1.13, but possible to create manually in 1.12). The easiest way to do that would be creating a new world of that type and copying the "level.dat" file from it to your destination world (overwriting the one that is there already). This won't change anything about the already generated chunks, but leave any new ones empty.

Comment: while, yes this is true in normal circumstances, anything made with world painter is created to load the chunks painted specifically in the version it was made for. if you load that map in a new version, those chunks will be regenerated according to the seed rather than stay looking like the earth map I want. If I download the map in 1.12 and then immediately run it in 1.13, it will regenerate ALL of the chunks on the map. But if I run it in 1.12, it will still look like Earth as I explore it. I will try the third method, however, as it seems viable.

Comment: That sounds like a bug in the program or mod. You should report it. I'm also wondering how that can happen, because as far as I know, chunks that are saved have to be at least partially generated, so they wouldn't fully generate new.